# split data in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to split data input in here. help me, I'm stuck!

I've tried many ways but still don't work. Can I not?

```
public function insert(Request $request){

    $name = $request->input('name');



    if ($name == 13) {
        foreach ($name as $names) {
            echo $names = print_r(str_split($names)) . "</br>";
        }

    }else{
        $data = array('name'=>$name,);
        DB::table('badword')->insert($data);
        return redirect()->to('/inputan');
    }


}
```

the website keeps running but the split function doesn't

Comment: Please show some example input and expected output data.

Comment: show us what `dd($input)` gives, i guess this function never executes if block, only else block is being executed

Comment: `foreach ($name as $names) {
            print_r(str_split($names)) . "</br>";
        }`

Comment: Why are you doing a foreach on a Integer value?

Comment: I tried to enter the keycode "enter"

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `print_r` the way you are doing.

```
foreach ($name as $names) {
        echo $names = print_r(str_split($names),true) . "</br>";
    }
```

You need to add a [boolean true](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to assign print_r to a variable

Comment: I have added `true` in the `print_r`

Comment: `print_r(str_split($names),true)`

Comment: cannot change. remains the same

Comment: ohh lord i'm stuck

Comment: add `print_r($name)` before foreach loop